# Disable interaction during reloading a uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I try allowselection:NO but my app crashed. This is my code:

```
-(void)reloadTableView{


    [subscriptionTable setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [subscriptionTable reloadData];

    [subscriptionTable setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reloadData` is synchronous, till the time your table is reloading user interaction will not work by default. if your app is crashing, there is problem with some other part of your code.

Comment: where did you find that it's synchronous? I have a case where I use a UIButton in a custom cell, and it happens that I can change the switch while the reload is in progress. In that case, I've found that the indexPath to the cell is nil, probably because the reload first invalidates all cells, but still shows them, and my app crashed because of force unwrapping the indexPath in cellForIndexPath. I've found this using print() logs. I'm currently looking for the best workaround